# I need to find the Euler number of an image along with number of upstream concavities and conxexities in the image

Tags: matlab, eulers-number

I m using MATLAB. This is the code I have written

```
 I = imread('image.tif');
 imshow(I);
 title('Original');
 eul = bweuler(I,8);
 CH = bwconvhull(BW);
bwlabel()
```

it is giving me Euler number but not giving the number of concavities. I know I m missing something in the last part. can you please explain me what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for number of holes in each object on your image, I'd do rather like this (see manual for the [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) function):

```
I = imread('circles.png');  
% assuming that I is logical (binary) image
I = [ I fliplr(I) ; flipud(I) I];   % just to make image bigger

figure;
Props = regionprops(I,{'image','filledImage'});
NRegions = length(Props);
for k=1:NRegions
    DiffImage = Props(k).FilledImage-Props(k).Image;
    strT = sprintf('Region %d of %d',k,NRegions);
    subplot(2,2,1); imshow(Props(k).Image);       title([strT ': Original image']);
    subplot(2,2,2); imshow(Props(k).FilledImage); title([strT ': Filled image']);
    subplot(2,2,3); imshow(DiffImage);            title([strT ': Filled-Original image']);
    drawnow;
    pause(1); % allows to see the images
    [L, NHoles] = bwlabel(Props(k).FilledImage-Props(k).Image,8);
    fprintf('%s has %d holes\n',strT,NHoles);
end
```

Comment: not looking for holes , looking for concavities. but thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Seems that you should investigate all the properties the `regionprops` function can calculate.